pdflatex and TikZ Externalization Issues despite Successful Path Configuration
Question:
I'm currently facing an issue with pdflatex not being recognized as an internal or external command when attempting to compile a LaTeX document that includes TikZ graphics with externalization enabled. Here's the background of my setup and the steps I have taken to troubleshoot the problem.
System and Setup

Operating System: Windows
LaTeX Distribution: MiKTeX 4.19 (MiKTeX 24.4), installed at C:\Users\jetin\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\.
Editor: I am compiling using pdflatex from both the command line and my LaTeX editor (TexMaker).

Problem Description
When compiling a .tex file with TikZ externalization, I receive the error:
'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

However, pdflatex is indeed installed and recognized in the PATH.
Troubleshooting Steps and Results
Here is a summary of all the checks and tests I've performed:

PATH Configuration: I verified that pdflatex is in the PATH by running pdflatex --version from the command line. The command returns successfully:
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.19 (MiKTeX 24.4)


-shell-escape Option: I tested the -shell-escape option by running a simple LaTeX document using pdflatex -shell-escape test_file.tex, and it worked without issues.

Write Permissions: I confirmed that there are write permissions in the relevant directories by testing a temporary directory, which succeeded.

TikZ Externalization Setup: In the LaTeX document preamble, I have the following configuration to enable externalization:
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize


Compilation Attempt: Despite these checks, the compilation fails specifically when trying to externalize the TikZ graphics.


Additional Notes
Given the above steps, it seems that both pdflatex and the -shell-escape option work independently, but I still encounter the recognition error when TikZ externalization is used. It’s unclear whether this is a PATH, permissions, or other environment-specific issue.
Could there be additional configuration or steps I am overlooking to get pdflatex to work smoothly with TikZ externalization on Windows?
Thank you for any insights or recommendations!

I've never gotten externalize to run either.  I use standalone instead.

@JohnKormylo Agreed, but I actually need the feature to create file-figure1, ..., file-figureN to create graphs with parameters.

All extrenalize does is run standalone itself.  Not sure how it sets the name,  but you can always create a shortcut to permanently rename it.  You only have to rerun the standalone when you actually change the tikzpicture code.

Make a complete example that can be used for a test and show the exact command you are using on the command line to run it. Show also the log file.
